# What are the races in One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

**What are the races in One Piece?**

We know that there are Humans (Ex: Luffy), Fish-man (Ex: Arlong) and Giants (Ex: Dorry and Brogy). So what other races are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [website](https://www.quora.com/What-are-all-of-the-races-in-One-Piece), it have 36 races.

- Human
- Giants
- Dwarves/Tontatta Tribe
- Longarm Tribe
- Longleg Tribe
- Snakeneck Tribe
- Three-Eye Tribe
- Mink Tribe
- Kinokibito
- Yeti
- Fishmen
- Merfolk
- Skypieans
- Shandians
- Birkman
- Merveillians
- Automata
- Cyborgs
- Clones
- Modified Humans
- Space Pirates
- Kumate Tribe
- Okama
- Nomads
- Kuja
- Torino Tribe
- World Nobles
- Wotans
- Longlimb Humans
- Zombies
- Centaurs
- Satyrs
- Harpy
- Toys
- Homies
- Klabautermann

Comment: A lot of these are redundant if we're taking races to refer to different species. World Nobles, Okama, Kuja, etc. are all humans. Space pirate is more likely a profession than a race. Not sure if I'd consider modified human as a different race but if we are Satyr, Centaur and Harpy are inside of that since Monet was originally human and was then modified. Longlimb humans is the overarching term for longarms and longlegs so it should be one or the other. The homies created by big Mom's powers are just inanimate objects infused with human souls. Clones are still whatever race they're clones of.

Answer (score 1):

That list is wrong:

- Human (most of the characters we know)
- Giants (Saul, Dory, Brogy)
- Dwarves/Tontatta Tribe (Mansherry, Leo)
- Longarm Tribe (Apoo, Ideo)
- Longleg Tribe (Blue Gilly, Smoothy)
- Snakeneck Tribe (Mascarpone, Amande)
- Three-Eye Tribe (Pudding)
- Mink Tribe (Carrot, Pedro)
- Kinokobito (unnamed one on a book at WCI)
- Yeti (the Yeti Cool Brothers)
- Fishmen (Jinbe, Arlong)
- Merfolk (Shirahoshi, Neptune)
- Skypieans (Connie, Pagaya)
- Shandians (Wyper, Kalgara)
- Bierkan (Uruge, Enel)
- Ancient Giant (Oars, Little Oars Jr.)

> * Lunarian (King)

- Space Pirates (we don't know the race, but they are definitely something unknown)

People from the artificial archipelago Merveille, from the Kumate tribe, from the Kuja tribe, from the Torino tribe, or members of the Celestial Dragons are Humans, so already listed.

Automata, Cyborgs, Modified Humans, Clones, Zombies, Centaurs, Satyrs, Harpy, Toys, Homies are artificial (created by a DF or modified from any species)

Okama and Nomads can be from any species, they are not genetically different, it's just the way they choose to live their lives

Longlimb Humans are Long-Arm and Long-Leg humans, already listed separately

Anyone born of a fishman and a giant is a Wotan, it's not a race.

Klabautermann is not a race of living beings, but the soul of an inanimate object

So 18, and there's a hint of a 19th in WCI that might be revealed on this arc

Comment: This is actually a more accurate response and more explained.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but this is the real answer.

1. Humans (this apparently includes Long-Limbs and other wacky ethnicities).
2. Fishmen/Merfolk (different ethnicities & species; one race).
3. Giants.
4. Skypieans (Including the Birkans, people like Enel).
5. Minks.
6. Dwarves / "Fairies" / Tontatta Tribe.
7. Tribal races w/ ethnicities like the Three-Eyed & Snakeneck (apparently humanoid but not human).
8. [This final one is an end-of-Wano or Final-Saga spoiler. I myself got spoiled so I can't confirm or deny.]

(There are only 8 races because of a One Piece theory about the Void Century. But the theory also admits that it might be 10 -- depending on which symbol is the truth. If ykyk, I guess.)

Comment: I think this isn't a complete answer unless you explain what the "theory about the Void Century" *is*, and how it explains why there's only 8 races. It's okay to post spoilers here, as long as you hide them using a spoiler tag `>!`, like Esteban Nighma did in his answer.